# How to divide a string into multiple strings and reconstruct it back?

Tags: vb.net, string, split

I have a string that have a number of characters for example `"The quick fox jumped over the lazy dog"` and I want to divide it to multiple string each of them has two characters for example then I'll do a certain operation on them and I'll rejoin them back for example:

```
String(1) = "Th"
String(2) = "e "
String(3) = "qu"
String(4) = "ic"
```

And so on ...

And if the string can't be divided into equal strings of two characters (like "Dad" for example) it makes the last string consists of the last remaining letter, for example:

```
String(1) = "Da"
String(2) = "d"
```

I have tried the following code to generate variables:

```
    Dim String(69) As String

    For i As Integer = 0 To String.Length - 1
        String(i) = "some text"
     Next
```

And:

```
 Dim text As String
 For i As Integer = 0 To RichTextBox1.TextLength - 2 Step 2
 text = RichTextBox1.Text.Substring(i, 2)
 Next i
```

To divide the sting (richtextbox1.text) into equal parts it worked but it I can't do anything on each substring.

Thanks!

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Please read the [guide to asking a good question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) and show [what you have tried](http://whatyouhavetried.com).

Comment: What part of the task are you having trouble with?  Are you familiar with `For`, `String.SubString`, and `String.Join`?

Comment: The answer seems so obvious that I'm tempted to answer but, thats exactly why you should at least try.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GroupBy` on the index:

```
Dim twoLetterWords = "The quick fox jumped over the lazy dog".
        Select(Function(c, i) New With {.Char = c, .Index = i}).
        GroupBy(Function(x) CInt(Math.Floor(x.Index / 2))).
        Select(Function(g) String.Join("", g.Select(Function(x) x.Char)))
```

So if you want to have a three-letter words instead, change `x.Index / 2` to `x.Index / 3`.

Here the result in the debugger (ideone doesn't work well with VB)

[image]

> But how can I do something on each of the substrings (for example
>   adding number 1 in the first one then 2 in the second string and so
>   on) ?

I assume you are not familiar with Linq. You can use a simple `For Each` to enumerate the query, you could materialize it to a collection-type, f.e. by using `ToList` which creates a new `List(Of String)`. Then you can access each string also with a `For-Loop`. Or you could rewrite the query to add your number in the first place(recommended):

To add the number of the string in the sequence(1-19 in this case) at the front, change the last line of the query above to:

```
Select(Function(g, index) String.Format("({0}) {1}", 
                          index + 1, 
                          String.Join("", g.Select(Function(x) x.Char))))
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: But how can I do something on each of the substrings (for example adding number 1 in the first one then 2 in the second string and so on) ?

Comment: @SamuelMedhat: Edited my answer accordingly. Added the number (wrapped in round brackets) at the front of each string.

Comment: Can I have your e-mail so that we can communicate better?

Answer (score 0):

To Extend [Tim Schmelter's already good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14627915/659190)

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module SplitTest
    Sub Main()
        For Each pair In "abcdef".Split(2)
            Console.WriteLine(pair)
        Next

        Console.ReadKey
    End Sub

    <Extension()>
    Public Function Split(ByVal source As String, ByVal length As Integer) _
               As IEnumerable(Of String)

        Return source.Select(Function(c, i) New With {c, i}) _
            .GroupBy(Function(t) t.i \ length) _
            .Select(Function(g) String.Concat(g.Select(Function(t) t.c)))
    End Function
End Module
```

You could package the linq into an extension and test it like this.

---

The only problem with using `GroupBy` is that its probably not smart enough to know the index will always increase. This means that the whole string will need to be enumerated before any results are yielded.

Since VB.net has no `yield return` I think it is probably still as good as you can do.

---

If your string were **very** long, you might want to use a bit of c# so you could start yeilding results before the whole string was read.

An good example is [hosted here](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/Batch.cs)

Answer (score 0):

1. divide the length of the string by 2 (remember to +1 if there is a remainder)
2. learn about iteration
3. learn about SubString()